# what are the pros and cons of bunyan and winston?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am new to Nodejs .Confused in opting between bunyan and winston ! would anyone please make me clear on the pros and cons of those two modules .

Answer (score 7):

Checks this links, You will get some clear idea

https://strongloop.com/strongblog/compare-node-js-logging-winston-bunyan/
https://npmcompare.com/compare/bunyan,winston

**Pros of Bunyan**

- Bunyan has a concept of a child logger to specialize a logger for a sub-component of application
- JSON based log

Mostly I prefer winston over Bunyan.